# how to install pecl extensions ( SSH2 ) on xampp?

Tags: php, ssh, xampp, pecl

my XAMPP php version is 5.4 and its Architecture is x86. i want to add pecl ssh2 extension and i've downloaded ssh2 pecl dll extension file for my xampp php and Architecture version . but when i add it to php\ext , it doesn't shown up into php.ini

Comment: Have you checked via `<?php echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');` whether you've edited the right php.ini? Is there any error in the error log?

Comment: yes,i've checked that and it is the true php.ini . but but there's nothing to show ssh2 extension